# Emma giving compile errors

Tags: junit, emma

I'm trying to integrate emma with an ant build, that does junit testing. 
My current code runs as : ant tests

I'm trying the offline instrumentation:
http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide_single/userguide.html#N10291

So I changed the target line to be:
target name="run" depends="init, test" description="runs the examples"

So I run ant emma run
However I get the following error:

commonstest:
    [junit] Running com.fourhome.commons.AllTests
    [junit] Tests run: 24, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.433 sec

run:

BUILD FAILED
C:\code\svn\core\core\trunk\build-targets.xml:929: Problem: failed to create tas
k or type emma
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

The failure line is:emma enabled="${emma.enabled}"

I'm guessing emma.enabled is not defined. How should I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs on the page you linked to, either `"true"` or `"false"`. From the `<emma>` task:

```
<target name="emma" description="turns on EMMA's on-the-fly instrumentation mode" >
  <property name="emma.enabled" value="true" />
</target>

<target name="run" depends="init, compile" description="runs the examples" >
    <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" >
      <instr instrpathref="run.classpath"#B0.5-co
             destdir="${out.instr.dir}" 
             metadatafile="${coverage.dir}/metadata.emma"
             merge="true"
      />
    </emma>
  </emmajava>
</target>
```

As you provide no context for the line in question, I'm guessing. If you search the same page you link to you will find other examples and tasks in which that property is used, how to set the property for a variety of scenarios, and how to use the auxiliary `"emma"` target. The above is a mix of two examples.

Comment: Thanks. I actually set the flat to true. It still says "Problem: failed to create task or type emma". Do I have to do something special to create the task emma?

Comment: @user761529 Define "special", you need to declare it using `<taskdef>` as shown in the same docs with an appropriate classpath ref.